# What's the difference between these two imports statement?

Tags: meteor, ecmascript-6

In Meteor 1.4, what's the difference between these two import statements in the client code and in the server code? Why?

Client code:

```
import { Items } from '../imports/api/items.js';
```

Server code:

```
import '../imports/api/items.js';
```

Comment: In the first snippet, there's an `Items` identifier that you can use in the module; in the second snippet there's not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both statements will execute the file given, however the first one will add Item to the scope. This can be useful if the file has many exports and you are only concerned with that single class/function/object/etc.

The second is used for side effects provided from importing it (like initializing a store or something like that; I confess I don't know much about meteor).

Mozilla has a great resource on the import statement https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: With the server code you will also import the `Items` collection then, right? It's just that with the client code you're doing *only* that compared to the server code that it's executing whatever it's inside that file.

Comment: "Import an entire module for side effects only, without importing any bindings." What does `for side effects only, without importing any bindings` mean?

Comment: While I don't know much about meteor it is possible its just initializing the store or adding it to a name space or something.

Comment: @FredCollins No, an import always executes the file. The one that use `{…} from` will however also make an exported variable available inside the current module. So no, in the "server code" the export might be created but `Items` is *not* imported.

Comment: @Bergi so in the "server code" the Items cannot be accessed?

Comment: @FredCollins That's what I said, yes. You can also simply try it out.